# Gremlin OLAP traversal query error regarding local star-graph

Tags: olap, tinkerpop, janusgraph, tinkerpop3, graph-traversal

I'm trying to execute an OLAP traversal on a query that needs to check if a vertex has a neighbour of certain type.
i keep getting

***Local traversals may not traverse past the local star-graph on GraphComputer***

my query looks something like:

```
g.V().hasLabel('label1').
where(_.out().hasLable('label2'))
```

I'm using the TraversalVertexProgram.
needless to say, when running the same query in oltp mode there is no problem
is there a way to execute such logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is limitation of TinkerPop OLAP GraphComputer. It operate on 'star-graph' objects. The vertex and connected edges only. It uses message passing engine inside. So you have to rewrite you query.

Option 1: start from label2 and go t label1. This should return the same result

```
g.V().hasLabel('label2').in().hasLabel('label1')
```

Option2: try to use unique edge labels and check edge label instead

```
g.V().hasLabel('label1').where(_.outE('label1_label2'))
```